# How can i get a list of Media class and it returns two entities?

Tags: java, spring, hierarchy

I have two classes Video and Photo in a spring web application,using jpa, mysql, amazon s3, What i want is to be able to return in my view a list of Media meaning both video and photos together as one Entity. Is there a way to do this. i need an idea.

Idea

If i create a Media class and make photo and video extend this class will that in a way help? Is there a way to say getMediaList and its returns video and entity  ordered by date of creation ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you could in fact create an abstract `Media` class, and make both the `Video` and `Photo` classes extend from it.

To order all your elements in a `List<Media>`, you could implement a *`sort`* method that makes use of a comparator on a date field.

As an example, the classes could be organised as follows:

```
public abstract class Media {
    protected Date createdOn;
    protected String name;

    protected Date getCreationDate() {
        return createdOn;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public static void sort(List<Media> movieItems) {
        movieItems.sort(Comparator.comparing(Media::getCreationDate));
    }
}
```

```
public class Video extends Media {
    private String someAttribute;

    public Video(Date date, String name) {
        createdOn = date;
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

```
public class Photo extends Media {
    private String someOtherAttribute;

    public Photo(Date date, String name) {
        createdOn = date;
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

The following code

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create first element
        Date date1 = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
        Video video1 = new Video(date1, "Timelapse");

        // Create second element
        Date date2 = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000);
        Photo photo1 = new Photo(date2, "My pretty picture");

        // Create list
        ArrayList<Media> myMedia = new ArrayList<>();
        myMedia.add(video1);
        myMedia.add(photo1);

        // Original
        System.out.println("Original list:");
        printMediaList(myMedia);

        // Sorted
        System.out.println("Sorted list:");
        Media.sort(myMedia);
        printMediaList(myMedia);
    }

    public static void printMediaList(List<Media> myMedia) {
        for (int i = 0; i < myMedia.size(); i++) {
            System.out.printf("%d. %s\n", i + 1, myMedia.get(i).getName());
        }

        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

outputs this

```
Original list:
1. Timelapse
2. My pretty picture

Sorted list:
1. My pretty picture
2. Timelapse
```

Hope this helps.