# Round icon of MediaItem on AndroidAuto App

Tags: java, android, android-auto

[image]

MediaItem Builder maynot support round icon

Is there a way to make a list of media item which has a round icon (because currently i just have the square one). I do think about using Glide to load it as asynchronize but it looks not good.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can i get a list of Media class and it returns two entities?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56207463/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-media-class-and-it-returns-two-entities)

Comment: you can use List

Comment: Hm... Exactly not, i think the Spotify round the image in the server not client.